# Django and GAE: Strange delay inside authentication

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, google-app-engine-python

So I've got this Django application (more specifically, Django Rest Framework) up there on Google's app engine. Mostly it works fine, except once in a while, I hit a strange delay (from 4-5s to 10-20 seconds...) This delay happens while authenticating the user and before I hit the view itself. I have already crossed out two theories :

- Delays caused by starting and setting up a new instance : I'm already using the warmup option for python instances (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_Warmup_requests)
- Cloud SQL-related delays. The application talks with Cloud SQL to authenticate the user, although I've logged every SQL queries and the delay happens before any queries are made.

So if it's not related to GAE's architecture and not limited by RPC... what's happening? I've plugged in cProfile and here's what it can tells us (I wrapped cProfile around the wsgi handler) :[image: cProfile sample inside the console backend for GAE]

Please note the line in the middle : around 10000 "len" calls. This same profiling report is devoid of such a line, usually. Only these requests with this absurd delay contains these 10000s of "len" calls.

This might indicate a very long query to Cloud SQL, but as I've said beforehand, the queries logged happens **after**. Or there is maybe a glitch in the SQL logging... Maybe.

Comment: I suspect this is either 1) bad logging or 2) connection delays. Maybe it's trying to check/retry a connection 1000 times and that's done using `len`? That would explain both the delay (connection timing out) and the strange `len` calls in those cases.

Comment: I believe Django's auth hashes passwords 24000 times to be intentionally slow. Could this be related?

Comment: I should have also mentioned: Django Debug Toolbar will help you easily find the bottleneck. https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: @FlipperPA - This app has a username / password auth as well as a token based auth. So no password hash-calculation in one mode of auth - and this issue happens with both types of auth. So I believe this is not related to any hashing-related latency.

Comment: I can't help but feel this problem is very similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970611/django-query-extremely-slow